# How to call and run next function if previous function runs in infinite loop?

Tags: python

I have two different python files, one runs a web socket connection that runs in infinite loop until stopped and the second one has code that calculates data based on the first file data stored in DB.

I have created a function in both the files and calling them in a third file for easy execution. But the problem is when I execute the first function the code never goes to the second function as first one is on infinite loop.

Is there any way to solve this?

What I am trying to do is gathering data from web socket connection and parallelly run the next file and do some calculation in real time based on the data.

Comment: Either run them in different threads, or redesign the first function so that it can yield to the second function (e.g. make it a generator, and call it in a loop that passes each yielded value to the second function).

Comment: Socket processing is one case where multithreading works well in Python.  You can start your socket listener in a thread, then have it feed stuff into a queue that your second function waits for.

Comment: You could also use a little shell script that starts the server script as a background job, then runs the evaluation script as needed.